# Validation in angular UI not working on page load

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a page which has several rows and I have certain validation placed such as at least one Key,Time and Input should be selected.
The validation works fine on first time.However when I save the state of the page and reload the page then by default those rows are selected as Key and Time and Input. However the Next or Save button is not enabled now although the validations are true. So to enable the Save and Nextbutton I need to deselect and select a row as Key again.

```
let key = this.columnList.filter(column => column.type == 'Key' && column.selected == true);
let time = this.columnList.filter(column => column.type == 'Time' && column.selected == true);
let segment = this.columnList.filter(column => column.type == 'Segment' && column.selected == true);
let quantile = this.columnList.filter(column => column.type == 'Quantile' && column.selected == true);
let input = this.columnList.filter(column => column.type == 'Input' && column.selected == true);
if (key.length >= 1 && time.length >= 1 && (input.length != 0 && (segment.length != 0 || quantile.length != 0))) {
  this.validateSegInput = true;
}
else {
  this.validateSegInput = false;
}
```

On page load my page looks like this even though all the validations are true
[image]

After this i have to set one dropbox as not and then set it again as time to make the button enabled.

Comment: Can you provide more info? Where is the code snippet being executed? Which version of Angular? Are you using lifecycle hooks? etc.

Comment: Angular 7, No I am not using any lifecycle hooks. The code i am using for vaidation in pasted above in question

Comment: I know. The code validation isn't the problem, it's *where* it's being executed, and more specifically *when*.

i.e, if you were executing this code inside `ngOnInit` it would execute on every page load, so your validations would fire.

Comment: I am executing it outside ngOnInit. However if i place whole function inside ngOnInit it throws error

Comment: You need to be more descriptive. What are the errors, what does the component look like, is it a form? Are you using angular forms? Throwing some code onto your question, which doesn't show the actual problem, is no good to anyone trying to help you. We need much more context that this. On the face of it, the validation code is not the problem.

Comment: I have added screenshot.Please let me know if you want me to add something else too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186041/discussion-between-prettyfly-and-saad).

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the relevant code in its entitreity, it's difficult to offer a substantial answer. However, as a general rule, any validation logic that you need to run on each page load, should be inside the `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook. However, if that validation depends on the view being rendered first, then you should use the `ngAfterViewChecked` lifecycle hook.

An alternative, would be to move your validation logic into a function of its own, and return a boolean. Then you can use that function to determine your button state.

i.e

```
 validateKeyTime() {
    let key = this.columnList.filter(column => column.type == 'Key' && column.selected == true); 
    let time = this.columnList.filter(column => column.type == 'Time' && column.selected == true); 
    let segment = this.columnList.filter(column => column.type == 'Segment' && column.selected == true); 
    let quantile = this.columnList.filter(column => column.type == 'Quantile' && column.selected == true); 
    let input = this.columnList.filter(column => column.type == 'Input' && column.selected == true); 
    if (key.length >= 1 && time.length >= 1 && (input.length != 0 && (segment.length != 0 || quantile.length != 0))) { 
         return true;
    }

    return false;
 }
```

Now, on your button, you can use:

```
<button [disabled]="!validateKeyTime()">Save</button>
```

Anywhere else you need to use the value of `validateSegInput`, you can either call the function directly in its place, or, you can use the `ngOnChanges` lifecycle hook to update the `validateSegInput` variable from the result of `validateKeyTime()`. Or, you can simply update that value inside of the function, and still return a boolean. It's entirely up to you.

The *ideal* scenario here though, would be to use Angulars built in forms and validation, by creating a `FormGroup` from your columns, with `Validators.required`. That way, your checks can be as simple as `myFormGroup.valid`